# ¿Cómo conseguir que un elemento siempre este abajo de su contenedor?

Tags: html, css, html5, diseño

Estoy teniendo un problema de diseño, estoy adaptando una pagina y noto el siguiente error de diseño:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se observa en la imagen, el botón naranja "Ver propiedad" se adapta, pero solo en su div, y en los otras deja un espacio en blanco, quiero conseguir que sin importar el tamaño del contenedor (Que es un `<div>`) siempre este al final de este.

Intente hacer que el elemento tome el 100% de su tamaño, pero no logro que se vea hasta abajo.
A continuación el código:

```css
/**CSS**/

/**Generales**/
    html {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        font-size: 62.5%;
        /** Reset para REMS - 62.5% = 10px de 16px **/
    }
    
    *,
    *:before,
    *:after {
        box-sizing: inherit;
    }
    
    body {
        font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
        font-size: 1.6rem;
        line-height: 2;
    }
    /** Globales **/
    
    img {
        max-width: 100%;
    }
    
    .contenedor {
        width: 95%;
        max-width: 120rem;
        /** = 1200px; **/
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    
    h1 {
        font-size: 3.8rem;
    }
    
    h2 {
        font-size: 3.4rem;
    }
    
    h3 {
        font-size: 3rem;
    }
    
    h4 {
        font-size: 2.6rem;
    }
    /** Utilidades **/
    
    .seccion {
        margin-top: 2rem;
        margin-bottom: 2rem;
    }
    
    .fw-300 {
        font-weight: 300;
    }
    
    .centrar-texto {
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    .d-block {
        display: block!important;
    }
    
    .contenido-centrado {
        max-width: 800px;
    }
    
/**Contenido del anuncio**/
 @media (min-width: 768px) {
        .contenedor-anuncios {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
        }
    }
    
    
        .anuncio {
        border: 1px solid #B5B5B5;
        background-color: #F5F5F5;
        margin-bottom: 2rem;
    }
    
    @media (min-width: 768px) {
        .anuncio {
            flex: 0 0 calc(33.3% - 1rem);
            word-break: break-all;
        }
    }
    
    @media (max-width: 768px) {
        .anuncio {
            word-break: break-all;
        }
    }
    
    .contenido-anuncio {
        padding: 2rem;
    }
    
    .contenido-anuncio h3,
    .contenido-anuncio p {
        margin: 0;
    }
    
        .precio {
        color: #71B100;
        font-weight: 700;
    }
    
    /** Botones **/
    
    .boton {
        color: #ffffff;
        font-weight: 700;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 1.8rem;
        padding: 1rem 3rem;
        margin-top: 3rem;
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: center;
        border: none;
        display: block;
        flex: 0 0 100%;
    }
    
    @media (min-width: 768px) {
        .boton {
            display: inline-block;
            flex: 0 0 auto;
        }
    }
    
    .boton:hover {
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    .boton-amarillo {
        background-color: #E08709;
    }
    
    /**Img**/
    
        .limitar {
        max-width: auto;
        height: 40rem;
    }
```

```html
<!--HTML-->


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>



    <div class="contenedor-anuncios">

        <!---->
        <div class="anuncio">
            <center>
                <img class="limitar" src="https://i.postimg.cc/Hspfjd8p/118997693-1002361023562635-4414947189969988165-n.jpg" alt="Anuncio casa en el lago">
            </center>
            <div class="contenido-anuncio bajo">
                <div>
                    <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
                    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
                    <p class="precio">0000</p>
                    <p>xxxx</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <a href="#" class="boton boton-amarillo d-block">Ver Propiedad</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!---->
        <!---->
        <div class="anuncio">
            <center>
                <img class="limitar" src="https://i.postimg.cc/Hspfjd8p/118997693-1002361023562635-4414947189969988165-n.jpg" alt="Anuncio casa en el lago">
            </center>
            <div class="contenido-anuncio bajo">
                <div>
                    <h3>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</h3>
                    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
                    <p class="precio">0000</p>
                    <p>xxxxx</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <a href="#" class="boton boton-amarillo d-block">Ver Propiedad</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!---->
        <!---->
        <div class="anuncio">
            <center>
                <img class="limitar" src="https://i.postimg.cc/Hspfjd8p/118997693-1002361023562635-4414947189969988165-n.jpg" alt="Anuncio casa en el lago">
            </center>
            <div class="contenido-anuncio bajo">
                <div>
                    <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
                    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
                    <p class="precio">0000</p>
                    <p>xxxxx</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <a href="#" class="boton boton-amarillo d-block">Ver Propiedad</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!---->


    </div>
    </main>

</html>
```

En el ejemplo se puede observar el problema que describo, ¿Alguna idea de como hacer que sin importar el tamaño del contenedor el link siempre(Boton "Ver propiedad") este hasta abajo?

De antemano muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya que estás usando flex, adiciona estas modificaciones a tu css:

```
.anuncio {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
}
.contenido-anuncio {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   flex-grow: 2;
   justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```css
/**CSS**/

/**Generales**/
    html {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        font-size: 62.5%;
        /** Reset para REMS - 62.5% = 10px de 16px **/
    }
    
    *,
    *:before,
    *:after {
        box-sizing: inherit;
    }
    
    body {
        font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
        font-size: 1.6rem;
        line-height: 2;
    }
    /** Globales **/
    
    img {
        max-width: 100%;
    }
    
    .contenedor {
        width: 95%;
        max-width: 120rem;
        /** = 1200px; **/
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    
    h1 {
        font-size: 3.8rem;
    }
    
    h2 {
        font-size: 3.4rem;
    }
    
    h3 {
        font-size: 3rem;
    }
    
    h4 {
        font-size: 2.6rem;
    }
    /** Utilidades **/
    
    .seccion {
        margin-top: 2rem;
        margin-bottom: 2rem;
    }
    
    .fw-300 {
        font-weight: 300;
    }
    
    .centrar-texto {
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    .d-block {
        display: block!important;
    }
    
    .contenido-centrado {
        max-width: 800px;
    }
    
    .anuncio {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
  }
    .contenido-anuncio {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      flex-grow: 2;
      justify-content: space-between;
  }
    
/**Contenido del anuncio**/
 @media (min-width: 768px) {
        .contenedor-anuncios {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
        }
    }
    
    
        .anuncio {
        border: 1px solid #B5B5B5;
        background-color: #F5F5F5;
        margin-bottom: 2rem;
    }
    
    @media (min-width: 768px) {
        .anuncio {
            flex: 0 0 calc(33.3% - 1rem);
            word-break: break-all;
        }
    }
    
    @media (max-width: 768px) {
        .anuncio {
            word-break: break-all;
        }
    }
    
    .contenido-anuncio {
        padding: 2rem;
    }
    
    .contenido-anuncio h3,
    .contenido-anuncio p {
        margin: 0;
    }
    
        .precio {
        color: #71B100;
        font-weight: 700;
    }
    
    /** Botones **/
    
    .boton {
        color: #ffffff;
        font-weight: 700;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 1.8rem;
        padding: 1rem 3rem;
        margin-top: 3rem;
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: center;
        border: none;
        display: block;
        flex: 0 0 100%;
    }
    
    @media (min-width: 768px) {
        .boton {
            display: inline-block;
            flex: 0 0 auto;
        }
    }
    
    .boton:hover {
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    .boton-amarillo {
        background-color: #E08709;
    }
    
    /**Img**/
    
        .limitar {
        max-width: auto;
        height: 40rem;
    }
```

```html
<!--HTML-->


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>



    <div class="contenedor-anuncios">

        <!---->
        <div class="anuncio">
            <center>
                <img class="limitar" src="https://i.postimg.cc/Hspfjd8p/118997693-1002361023562635-4414947189969988165-n.jpg" alt="Anuncio casa en el lago">
            </center>
            <div class="contenido-anuncio bajo">
                <div>
                    <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
                    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
                    <p class="precio">0000</p>
                    <p>xxxx</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <a href="#" class="boton boton-amarillo d-block">Ver Propiedad</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!---->
        <!---->
        <div class="anuncio">
            <center>
                <img class="limitar" src="https://i.postimg.cc/Hspfjd8p/118997693-1002361023562635-4414947189969988165-n.jpg" alt="Anuncio casa en el lago">
            </center>
            <div class="contenido-anuncio bajo">
                <div>
                    <h3>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</h3>
                    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
                    <p class="precio">0000</p>
                    <p>xxxxx</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <a href="#" class="boton boton-amarillo d-block">Ver Propiedad</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!---->
        <!---->
        <div class="anuncio">
            <center>
                <img class="limitar" src="https://i.postimg.cc/Hspfjd8p/118997693-1002361023562635-4414947189969988165-n.jpg" alt="Anuncio casa en el lago">
            </center>
            <div class="contenido-anuncio bajo">
                <div>
                    <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
                    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
                    <p class="precio">0000</p>
                    <p>xxxxx</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <a href="#" class="boton boton-amarillo d-block">Ver Propiedad</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!---->


    </div>
    </main>

</html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!, eso soluciono el problema!